# Seaborn heatmap clipping y-axis tick labels

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm attempting to create a heatmap with a DataFrame with rows like:

```
у     7.14e-02  4.29e-01  5.00e-01
ф     0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00
х     0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00
ц     0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00
ч     0.00e+00  9.75e-01  2.50e-02
ш     0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00
щ     0.00e+00  1.00e+00  0.00e+00
```

However, when I try to create a heatmap from this data, I end up with a y-axis that looks like this (note letters like у, ф, and ш with their bottom/right clipped off).

[image: y-axis]

Here's the code I'm using to initialize it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15)
plot = sns.heatmap(df_result, annot=True, fmt=".2f")
```

EDIT: I have tested replacing the Cyrillic character 'у' with the Latin character 'y' and it is no longer clipped. Any reason this issue would be specific to Cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 4):

The issue may be in the encoding when reading in the csv.

Here is the csv:

```
name,value1,value2,value3
у, 7.14e-02, 4.29e-01, 5.00e-01
ф, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00
х, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00
ц, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00
ч, 0.00e+00, 9.75e-01, 2.50e-02
ш, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00
щ, 0.00e+00, 1.00e+00, 0.00e+00
```

Read in the csv as:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

Save names list as y_labels and graph:

```
y_labels = df['name'].tolist()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15))
ax  = sns.heatmap(df[['value1','value2','value3']],
yticklabels =  y_labels)
```

y-axis labels are not cut off.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the yticks would help with the clipping.

```
degrees = 90
plt.yticks(rotation=degrees)
```

Or you could add some padding for the yaxis.

```
n = 15
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=n)
```

Documentation for padding with matplotlib can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).

Comment: Even with more padding and rotation, it's still clipped the same amount. I wonder if seaborn/matplotlib has an issue with Cyrillic characters specifically.